# Find all points on a line that intersect perfectly with a grid?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, 2d

I am trying to solve this math concept programmatically. Given two points `A` and `B`, on a rounded grid, find the points along the line from `A` to `B` that intersect with the rounded grid. I have looked into fast voxel traversal algorithms but they do not seem to only get points that are on the grid, instead just any points that intersect.

Here is a picture that might better describe my problem:

[image]

I am given the two orange points on any line, but I want to be able to find the blue points that that line intersects with. As you can see, the blue points are rounded to the grid.

Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: It seems like a general approach might be to formulate this as a Diophantine equation, which is related to the approach described by Paul below.

Answer (score 2):

There's two points that we know will always be aligned with the grid: the points at the end of the segment. I'll call them `a` and `b`. The vector describing the segment is then `b - a` (`v`).

`v` can be reduced while maintaining the ratio of the vector as follows:

```
v' = v / gcd(v_x, v_y)
```

where `v_x` and `v_y` are the `x` and `y`-components of `v` respectively. `v'` is the smallest possible vector with the same orientation as `v` consisting solely of integer components. This means that `a + v' * n` will be aligned to the grid for any `n` we may pick.

So the points on the line that are grid-aligned would be `[a + 0 * v', a + 1 * v', ..., a + m * v']`, where `a + m * v' = b` must hold. So we need to solve

```
a_x + m * v'_x = b_x
a_y + m * v'_y = b_y
```

which lead to

```
m = (b_x - a_x) / v'_x
m = (b_y - a_y) / v'_y
```

However there are three possible edge-cases to consider here:

- `a == b`: none of the equations are solveable (and there's exactly one grid-aligned point anyways)
- `v'_x == 0` or `v'_y == 0`: just pick the other equation to find `m`

Putting it all together as pythonesque pseudocode:

```
grid_aligned(a, b):
    if a == b:
        return [a]

    v = b - a
    v' = v / gcd(v.x, v.y)

    if v'.x == 0:
        m = v.y / v'.y
    else:
        m = v.x / v'.x

    return [a + v' * n for n in 0..m]
```